# How do I correctly unload an additive Scene in WebGL?

Tags: unity, webgl, loading, coroutines, scenemanager

I am creating an app in WebGL.  I have a loading scene that I am loading additively:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Loading Scene", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

It loads correctly.

Then after I finish loading everything, I remove the additive loading scene:

```
SceneManager.UnloadScene(SceneNames.Loading);
```

In the Editor, it unloads perfectly.  However, in browser, via WebGL, it gets called, but does not unload.  If I throw it in a coroutine and wait for 3 seconds, it does unload.

I have a two-part question:

1. Why does waiting for 3 seconds before unloading fix the problem?
2. What is the correct way to unload this scene so that there is not an arbitrary "Wait for seconds" in there?